# Python program hangs when producing a random number to index a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Edit (23 June 2023): **tl;dr I forgot to convert data types.**
>
> I was initially prevented from deleting this question and have now decided against it. This remains as a reminder to myself and others to thoroughly research questions.

**System**: `64-bit Windows 10 machine`

**Python installation**: `Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

**Editor**: original code from sublime text 3, now editing on VS code [latest stable build]

I am quite new to python, and have been working on a password manager program run in cmd.

I have used a function I made previously to generate random strings[passwords] to be stored in a file by main script. It is imported into main script from another py file.
the code hangs on the second line of code below in the while count != length loop[code from the imported script]
the exact same line of code had worked before
sorry the sample code is way too lengthy.

length: a variable defined by user input; turned into int to be used later

count: a variale is set to 0 before this loop

char_types: some lists of characters[upper case, lower case, symbols, numbers]

```
incl_upp = False
incl_low = False
incl_int = False
incl_sym = False
checklist = []
char_types = []
password = []
length = input('# input length of password in integers | ')
if input('# include upper case alpha? (y/n) | ') == 'y':
    incl_upp = True
    print("# password now includes upper case alpha")
if input('# include lower case alpha? (y/n) | ') == 'y':
    incl_low = True
    print("# password now includes lower case alpha")
if input('# include integers? (y/n) | ') == 'y':
    incl_int = True
    print("# password now includes integers")
if input('# include special characters? (y/n) | ') == 'y':
    print("# password now includes special characters")
    incl_sym = True
if incl_upp == True:
    char_types.append(UPPER_CASE)
    checklist.append(UPPER_CASE)
if incl_low == True:
    char_types.append(LOWER_CASE)
    checklist.append(LOWER_CASE)
if incl_int == True:
    char_types.append(NUMBERS)
    checklist.append(NUMBERS)
if incl_sym == True:
    char_types.append(SYMBOLS)
    checklist.append(SYMBOLS)
while True:
    count = 0
    while count != length:
        case = char_types[random.randint(0,int(len(char_types)-1))]
        char = case[random.randint(0,int(len(case)-1))]
        password.append(str(char))
        count = count + 1
    # for every char in password, for every type in list, for every character in type, check if that is in password
    for i in range(len(password)):
        for x in range(len(checklist)):
            for y in range(len(checklist[x])):
                if checklist[x[y]] in password[i]:
                    checklist[x] = True
    for i in range(len(checklist)):
        if checklist[i] != True or checklist[i] != False:
            checklist[i] = False
    if all(checklist):
        random.shuffle(password) # added security?
        password = "".join(password)
        return password
```

I have checked through the variables, data types and possible syntax errors, only to find nothing of suspicion.

It would be very much appreciated if anyone could provide some ideas as to how this problem is produced. I don't often post questions much here, so I apologise if this question seems incomplete.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the variable length?

Comment: Please provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and fix your indentation.

Comment: What is `length`? It's not referenced anywhere else in your code. The likely problem is that `length` is not what you're expecting.

Comment: sorry the question was incomplete, hope this edit helps

Comment: @albert it's kinda hard to create a MCVE, the code in the question relies on a bit of setup that would be hard to wade through. note: the code i have submitted is in a loop that checks if all character types are in the result list, to be later joined back [password.join('')]. but my issue is the program just hangs on the second line in the code in the question.  P.s. the indentation shows as valid in VS code, I do not understand what you find erroneous with it.

Comment: Best guess: you must have forgotten the data-type check when you take `length` from user input. Try do `length = int(length)` before the loop.

Comment: @Ian did that when taking input.

Comment: @AgentAzure007 the I suggest you put `print('%d  %d' %(count, length))` inside the loop to see what is really going on.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "password_manager.py", line 50, in <module>
    data[key] = generate()
  File "C:\Users\josep\Desktop\python\password_manager\config.py", line 54, in generate
    print('%d %d' % (count, length))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: got this, dunno what it means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert `length` to an integer after reading the user input. Otherwise you are comparing an integer with a string, which is never going to be equal. Hence you get in infinite loop.

```
length = int(input('# input length of password in integers | '))
```

Comment: Oh! thanks! terribly sorry, this was purely my own lack of care. Very sorry for wasting your time. your help is deeply appreciated. This question won't serve others well, will delete.